# Unable to check MPI option in QGIS while configuring plugin GIS4WRF

Tags: qgis, wrf-model

While configuring plugin GIS4WRF in QGIS, I tried to check MPI box it says mpich is not installed, even it is installed through homebrew in my system.
I have Mac M1-Max.
Can somebody help ?[image: not able to check mpich box in QGIS]

Answer (score 0):

I got solution
you just need to set the path for homebrew directory in Mac. Because in Intel Mac (before apple chip) homebrew directory was different.
I set this path in basic file

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/mpiexec:$PATH
```